# How to read a file using sparkstreaming and write to a simple file using Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, parquet

I'm trying to read a file using a scala SparkStreaming program. The file is stored in a directory on my local machine and trying to write it as a new file on my local machine itself. But whenever I write my stream and store it as parquet I end up getting blank folders.

This is my code :

```
 Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
 val spark = SparkSession
             .builder()
             .master("local[*]")
             .appName("StreamAFile")
             .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/temp")
             .getOrCreate()
 
         
 import spark.implicits._            
 val schemaforfile = new StructType().add("SrNo",IntegerType).add("Name",StringType).add("Age",IntegerType).add("Friends",IntegerType)
             
 val file = spark.readStream.schema(schemaforfile).csv("C:\\SparkScala\\fakefriends.csv")  

 file.writeStream.format("parquet").start("C:\\Users\\roswal01\\Desktop\\streamed") 
 
 spark.stop()
```

Is there anything missing in my code or anything in the code where I've gone wrong?

I also tried reading this file from a hdfs location but the same code ends up not creating any output folders on my hdfs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've mistake here:

```
val file = spark.readStream.schema(schemaforfile).csv("C:\\SparkScala\\fakefriends.csv")
```

csv() function should have directory path as an argument. It will scan this directory and read all new files when they will be moved into this directory

For checkpointing, you should add

```
.option("checkpointLocation", "path/to/HDFS/dir")
```

For example:

```
val query = file.writeStream.format("parquet")
    .option("checkpointLocation", "path/to/HDFS/dir")
    .start("C:\\Users\\roswal01\\Desktop\\streamed") 

query.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: `file.writeStream.parquet("C:\\Users\\roswal01\\Desktop\\streamed").start()`   here parquet seems to be giving an error, it shows that its not a member of DataStreamWriter. Have I missed on importing any packages?

Comment: It also gives a checkpoint error.

`checkpointLocation must be specified either through option("checkpointLocation", ...) or SparkSession.conf.set("spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation", ...);`

Comment: @RohanOswal Documentation seems to be outdated - sorry! I've removed this parquet() function from answer. I've also added information how to do checkpointing, it was - and probably is still - not always required and that's why I didn't include it

Comment: I still get blank folders as my output. The folder gets created but has no files inside it just a _spark_metadata folder which is again blank.

Comment: @RohanOswal Very strange. I will investigate it again and will post update :)

Comment: @RohanOswal Try `
 val query = file.writeStream.(...) ; query.awaitTermination()`