# How to read .csv files using spark streaming and write to parquet file using Scala?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, spark-streaming, parquet

I'm trying to read a file using spark 2.1.0 SparkStreaming program. The csv files are stored in a directory on my local machine and trying to use writestream parquet with a new file on my local machine . But whenever I try its always error in .parquet or getting blank folders.

This is my code :

```
case class TDCS_M05A(TimeInterval:String ,GantryFrom:String ,GantryTo:String ,VehicleType:Integer ,SpaceMeanSpeed:Integer ,CarTimes:Integer)

object Streamingcsv {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("Streamingcsv")
      .config("spark.master", "local")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._


    val schema = StructType(
        StructField("TimeInterval",DateType, false) ::
        StructField("GantryFrom", StringType, false) ::
        StructField("GantryTo", StringType, false) ::
        StructField("VehicleType", IntegerType, false) ::
        StructField("SpaceMeanSpeed", IntegerType, false) ::
        StructField("CarTimes", IntegerType, false) ::  Nil)


    import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders

    val usrschema = Encoders.product[TDCS_M05A].schema

    val csvDF = spark.readStream
      .schema(usrschema) // Specify schema of the csv files
      .csv("/home/hduser/IdeaProjects/spark2.1/data/*.csv")


    val query = csvDF.select("GantryFrom").where("CarTimes > 0")

    query
      .writeStream
      .outputMode("append")
      .format("parquet")
      .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint")
      .start("/home/hduser/IdeaProjects/spark2.1/output/")
      //.parquet("/home/hduser/IdeaProjects/spark2.1/output/")
      //.start()

    query.awaitTermination()
  }
```

I refer to the page [How to read a file using sparkstreaming and write to a simple file using Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41119084/how-to-read-a-file-using-sparkstreaming-and-write-to-a-simple-file-using-scala) 
and it isn't work, Please help me ,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the checkpoint directory exists (or create it) before you start. Your implementation of query should also include a val for query that is separate from your DF.

If you don't need to, don't put within an object containing empty args so you can directly access other methods like

```
 query.lastProgress
 query.stop
```

(to name a few)

Change the second half of your code to look like this.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.OutputMode

val csvQueriedDF = csvDF.select("GantryFrom").where("CarTimes > 0")

val query = csvQueriedDF
  .writeStream
  .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
  .format("parquet")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/home/hduser/IdeaProjects/spark2.1/partialTempOutput")
  .option("path", "/home/hduser/IdeaProjects/spark2.1/output/")
  .start()
```

Best of Luck!